# catkin_make builds executable in the wrong directory?

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I have a package I have been able to successfully build using catkin_make after setting up my package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. However, I have one problem. When I run catkin_make, it successfully makes the executable, but places the executable in catkin_ws/build/package_name. For example, I have made a small example below (**tbrandom and tbsub are my executables**):

```
may@MooMoo:~/Desktop/Tree/Programming/ros/TurtleBotRandom$ ls
build  devel  src
may@MooMoo:~/Desktop/Tree/Programming/ros/TurtleBotRandom$ cd build
may@MooMoo:~/Desktop/Tree/Programming/ros/TurtleBotRandom/build$ ls
catkin            catkin_make.cache  cmake_install.cmake  Makefile
catkin_generated  CMakeCache.txt     CTestTestfile.cmake  test_results
CATKIN_IGNORE     CMakeFiles         gtest                turtle_bot_random
may@MooMoo:~/Desktop/Tree/Programming/ros/TurtleBotRandom/build$ cd turtle_bot_random
may@MooMoo:~/Desktop/Tree/Programming/ros/TurtleBotRandom/build/turtle_bot_random$ ls
catkin_generated  cmake_install.cmake  Makefile  tbsub
CMakeFiles        CTestTestfile.cmake  tbrandom
```

When I source the devel/setup.bash, and try to run the executable through the package, ROS cannot find the executable unless I copy the executable(s) made (in this example, tbrandom and tbsub) and copy them into `Desktop/Tree/Programming/ros/TurtleBotRandom/src/turtle_bot_random`. This is really annoying for bigger projects which require more compile time, and then require me to copy paste files in between to actually start testing to see if my code even works.

What could be the reason or a potential fix? Am I doing something wrong? I've only started toying with catkin last night.

MY CMAKELISTS.TXT FILE:
http://www.pastebin.ca/3086592

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215057/catkin_make-builds-executable-in-the-wrong-directory?/) by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-08-01**:
If you post your CMakeLists.txt file I might be able to tell you what you need to do differently.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-08-02**:
+1 to what Dirk said: without your actual `CMakeLists.txt` we can only guess what is going on.

I'll take a guess though: was this package migrated from `rosbuild`? I've seen pkgs that forced rosbuild to place binaries in non-standard places. Catkin is different, and those pkgs then break.

**Comment by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on 2015-08-02**:
Hello guys, I have posted a link to a pastebin of my CMakeLists.txt file (it was too long to copy paste into the post). I hope this helps!

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2015-08-02**:
Your  Cmake ist worng

### Declare a cpp executable

- ## add_executable(turtle_bot_random_node src/turtle_bot_random_node.cpp)

you can not bild a Comment

**Comment by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on 2015-08-02**:
duck-development, if you look at lines 8-12, you will see that I have lines for my builds uncommented. I think you are looking at a line I commented out previously. I think I tried that thinking if I put in the path it would build the executable there, but commented it out when it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that you call `add_executable()` before `catkin_package()` in the CMake file.

Please read the documentation for more information: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on 2015-08-02**:
Thank you! That fixed the problem! However, the documentation doesn't seem to tell me *why* this caused an issue. Can you explain?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-08-03**:
Because the `catkin_package()` call changes the default location of compiled targets.

**Comment by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on 2015-08-03**:
Is this because catkin_package() overwrites the location to which the executables should be save?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-08-03**:
Yes, it changes the `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` and the `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH`.

**Comment by [utagai](https://answers.ros.org/users/22681/utagai/) on 2015-08-03**:
Alright, that makes sense. Thanks so much!